# How to replace values by NA in file 2 correspond to specified values in file 1?

Tags: r, binary, raster

I have two binary files(rasters) with the same dimensions. The first file is called `over`  and the second is `corr`. I want to replace values in `over` by `NA` whenever `corr` is greater than 0.5.

1. Read the first file:

   ```
   conn <- file("C:\\corr.bin", "rb")
   over <- readBin(conn, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
   y <- t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440))## binary
   r1 <- raster(t(matrix((data=over), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))## raster
   ```
2. Read the second file:

   ```
   conne <- file("C:\\cor06.bin", "rb")
   corr <- readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
   y1 <- t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440))## binary
   r <- raster(t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))##raster
   ```
3. Write the results:

   ```
   to.write = file(paste("/orcomplete.bin", sep=""), "wb")
   writeBin(as.double(results), to.write, size = 4)
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky to see exactly what you want, but what about:

```
over[corr > 0.5] = NA
```

or something a bit more complicated:

```
over[corr < 0.2 | corr > 0.4] = NA
```

Comment: That is fine:Thanks. what about if I want as a range, not higher than 0.5  but whenever `0.2 < corr > 0.4`. I want to assign it to t so I can write the result but  `t= over[corr > 0.4] = NA`
 `summary(over)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
   -1.0    -0.3     0.0    -0.1     0.2     0.4  947468` 
 `summary(t)`
   Mode    NA's 
logical       1 `. Could you please add this to your answer as well

Comment: You are starting to ask a different question. This is frowned upon in Stackoverflow since future readers can't follow what's going on. Instead, just as a new question.